Continuously Stream and Play Audio Chunks in Flutter Web?
I’ve been trying to implement streaming audio chunks (Uint8List) from an openAI tts-1 model in a Flutter Web app and playing them in sequence. The idea is to progressively fetch and buffer the audio as it's generated (e.g., from a TTS endpoint) and then play each buffered portion as soon as the previous one finishes.
What’s Happening:

The first chunk plays successfully.
Subsequent chunks fail to start, leading to errors like DEMUXER_ERROR_COULD_NOT_OPEN and NotSupportedError.

Errors:
Playing audio... PlayerState.completed
AudioPlayers Exception: AudioPlayerException(
    BytesSource(bytes: 7b444, mimeType: audio/mpeg), 
    PlatformException(WebAudioError, Failed to set source. For troubleshooting, see https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/troubleshooting.md, 
    MediaError: DEMUXER_ERROR_COULD_NOT_OPEN: FFmpegDemuxer: open context failed (Code: 4), null)
Error setting audio source: PlatformException(WebAudioError, Failed to set source. For troubleshooting, see https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/troubleshooting.md, 
    MediaError: DEMUXER_ERROR_COULD_NOT_OPEN: FFmpegDemuxer: open context failed (Code: 4), null)
Error: PlatformException(WebAudioError, Failed to set source.
    NotSupportedError: The element has no supported sources.

What I’ve Tried:

audioplayers: Using setSourceBytes on each buffered chunk works for the first chunk but fails on subsequent chunks.
just_audio: I attempted to use just_audio, but a streaming source is not available for the web.
JS Interop for Streaming: On the web, I’m not using http or dio for fetching. Instead, I rely on the browser’s Fetch API via JS interop (getReader()) to continuously read chunks as they become available. These chunks are then added to a queue and played in sequence.

Relevant Code:
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:collection';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:example/audio_player_controller.dart';
import 'package:example/tts_service_web.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: AudioStreamScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class AudioStreamScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const AudioStreamScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<AudioStreamScreen> createState() => _AudioStreamScreenState();
}

class _AudioStreamScreenState extends State<AudioStreamScreen> {
  // TODO: Add your API key
  final openAIKey = 'YOUR_OPENAI_API_KEY';

  final Queue<Uint8List> _bufferQueue = Queue();
  final BytesBuilder _currentBuffer = BytesBuilder();
  bool _isPlaying = false;
  final int _bufferSize = 64 * 1024; // Adjust this as needed
  AudioPlayerController? _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AudioPlayerController(onError: (e, s) {
      debugPrint('Error: $e');
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _fetchAndPlayAudio() async {
    final stream = TTSServiceWeb(openAIKey).tts(
      'https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/speech',
      {
        'model': 'tts-1',
        'voice': 'alloy',
        'speed': 1,
        'input': 'Lorem ipsum ...',
        'response_format': 'opus',
        'stream': true,
      },
    );

    try {
      await for (final chunk in stream) {
        _addToBuffer(chunk);
        if (_currentBuffer.length >= _bufferSize) {
          debugPrint('New Buffer: ${_currentBuffer.toBytes().lengthInBytes} / $_bufferSize');
          _flushBufferToQueue();
        }
        debugPrint('Last chunk: ${chunk.lengthInBytes / 1024} KB');
        _playNextInQueue();
      }
      _flushBufferToQueue(finalFlush: true);
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Error fetching audio: $e');
    }
  }

  void _addToBuffer(Uint8List chunk) {
    _currentBuffer.add(chunk);
  }

  void _flushBufferToQueue({bool finalFlush = false}) {
    if (_currentBuffer.isNotEmpty) {
      _bufferQueue.add(_currentBuffer.toBytes());
      _currentBuffer.clear();
    }
    if (finalFlush) {
      _playNextInQueue();
    }
  }

  Future<void> _playNextInQueue() async {
    if (_isPlaying || _bufferQueue.isEmpty) return;

    final nextChunk = _bufferQueue.removeFirst();
    _isPlaying = true;

    try {
      debugPrint('Playing chunk: ${nextChunk.lengthInBytes / 1024} KB');
      await _controller?.play(nextChunk);
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Error playing chunk: $e');
    } finally {
      _isPlaying = false;
      if (_bufferQueue.isNotEmpty) {
        _playNextInQueue();
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Audio Stream Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: _fetchAndPlayAudio,
          child: const Text('Play Audio'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Video Demo:
 Vimeo link: 
GitHub Repository:
 flutter_audio_streaming_prototype 
Questions:

Has anyone successfully implemented real-time streaming and playback of audio chunks on Flutter Web?
Are there alternative libraries or approaches that can handle a continuous stream of audio data on both web & mobile platforms?

Any insights, suggestions, or code examples would be greatly appreciated!
